# Orphaned case al iniciar un switch

Tags: java, netbeans

he tenido algunos errores al realizar un código para calcular el área de un triangulo y sus ángulos, pero a la hora de realizar el switch para los angulos, me genera dos errores, el primero se genera directamente en el switch (; expected) y al comenzar el case 1 me genera error (orphaned case)
me gustaria que alguien me ayudara a revisar en que tengo mal, cabe recalcar que aun no he acabado el codigo, pero no deberia de generar error

Ya revise los corchetes del switch y del if posterior y todos coinciden por lo que no deberia pedir ; a menos que tenga un error y no me haya dado cuenta, tampoco he hecho el segundo else if debido a que primero quiero solucionar este error para posteriormente dar continuidad al codigo

este es el codigo:

```
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Ingrese los valores de cada lado y de la altura para calcular el area");
    System.out.println("Ingrese el valor del lado a");
    double ladoa = entrada.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("Ingrese el valor del lado b");
    double ladob = entrada.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("Ingrese el valor del lado c");
    double ladoc = entrada.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("Ingrese el valor de la altura");
    double altura = entrada.nextFloat();
    
    double valora=0;
    double acosenoA=0;
    double gradosA=0;
    double angulob=0;
    double anguloc=0;
    
    double areaequilatero =(ladoc*altura)/2;
    
    double perimetro=ladoa+ladob+ladoc;
    double semiperimetro=perimetro/2;
    double areaisoscelesyescaleno;
    areaisoscelesyescaleno =Math.sqrt(semiperimetro*(semiperimetro-ladoa)*(semiperimetro-ladob)*(semiperimetro-ladoc));
    

    DecimalFormat formato= new DecimalFormat("#.0000");
    
    double gradosb=0;
    
    if(ladoa == ladob && ladob == ladoc && ladoa == ladoc) {
        System.out.println("El triangulo es equilatero");
        areaequilatero = (ladoc*altura)/2;
        System.out.println("El triangulo tiene un area de" + formato.format(areaequilatero)+"cm2");
    } else if (ladoa != ladob && ladob != ladoc && ladoa!=ladoc){
        System.out.println("El triangulo es escaleno");
        perimetro=ladoa+ladob+ladoc;
        semiperimetro=perimetro/2;
        areaisoscelesyescaleno =Math.sqrt(semiperimetro*(semiperimetro-ladoa)*(semiperimetro-ladob)*(semiperimetro-ladoc));
        System.out.println("El triangulo tiene un area de" + formato.format(areaisoscelesyescaleno)+"cm2");
    } else if (ladoa == ladob || ladob == ladoc || ladoa == ladoc) {
        System.out.println("El triangulo es isosceles");
        perimetro=ladoa+ladob+ladoc;
        semiperimetro=perimetro/2;
        areaisoscelesyescaleno =Math.sqrt(semiperimetro*(semiperimetro-ladoa)*(semiperimetro-ladob)*(semiperimetro-ladoc));
        System.out.println("El triangulo tiene un area de" + formato.format(areaisoscelesyescaleno)+"cm2");
    }
    
    valora = (Math.pow(ladoa, 2) - Math.pow(ladob, 2) - Math.pow(ladoc, 2))/-(2*ladob*ladoc);
    acosenoA=Math.acos(valora);
    gradosA= Math.toDegrees(acosenoA);
    
    System.out.println("Con el numero 1 revisamos el valor de los angulos y con el numero 2 cierras el sistema");
   int opcion = entrada.nextInt();
    
    Switch(opcion) {
    
        case 1:
        if(ladoa == ladob && ladob == ladoc && ladoa == ladoc){
            System.out.println("El triangulo equilatero siempre tiene 60° en cada uno de sus angulos, pues es un triangulo rectangulo");           
        }else if(ladoa != ladob && ladob != ladoc && ladoa != ladoc){
            valora = (Math.pow(ladoa, 2) - Math.pow(ladob, 2) - Math.pow(ladoc, 2));
            acosenoA = Math.acos(valora);
            gradosa= Math.toDegrees(acosenoA);
            
            
            double senoA = Math.sin(gradosa);
            angulob= (ladob*senoA)/ladoa;
            double acosenoB= Math.acos(angulob);
            gradosb= Math.toDegrees(acosenoB);
            
            senoA= Math.sin(gradosc);
            anguloc= (ladoc*senoA)/ladoc;
            double acosenoC = Math.acos(anguloc);
            double gradosc= Math.toDegrees(acosenoC);
            
            System.out.println("el triangulo escaleno tiene su angulo A "+ formato.format(gradosa) +"°, su angulo B "+formato.format(gradosb)+"° y su angulo C"+formato.format(gradosc)+"°");
            
        }else if (ladoa == ladob || ladob == ladoc || ladoa == ladoc){
            
        }
        
        
        
    }
    
}"
```

Comment: ES `switch` minuscula no `Switch`

Comment: te va a marcar otros error por que estas obviando el nombre de tus variables por ejemplo declaras `gradoA` pero lo usas como `gradoa,` revisa tu codigo

Comment: Mil gracias bro, ya revise :3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escribiste "Switch" cuando la palabra reservada para eso es "switch" en minúsculas.
Recuerda que lleva la siguiente forma, donde en caso de no colocar break al terminar el case, entonces se irá de corrido.

```
switch( valor ){
    case 1:
        ...
        break;
    case 2:
        ...
        break;
    case N:
        ...
        break;
    default:
        ...
}
```

Adicionalmente te falta hacer la declaración de "gradosa", definiste "gradosA", Java es supcetible a mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Adicionalmente, en la siguiente línea, usas primero una varibale que no has declarado y tres líneas después la usas, para solucionar declara la variable antes de usarla.

```
senoA= Math.sin(gradosc);
...
double gradosc= Math.toDegrees(acosenoC);
```

Saludos y sigue practicando.